# Simple HTML DOM not finding all elements

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to find every single `<a>` tag on https://www.racketspecialisten.se/kategorier/padel/padelracket/, but it's only finding the first 205 `<a>` tags, and I have no clue why.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://www.racketspecialisten.se/kategorier/padel/padelracket');
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    echo $element . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Cheers!

Comment: possibly the others are loaded through ajax? They do have 3 XHR events on page load

Comment: Yep, you're probably right. Found a pretty good workaround though if you're just trying to pull every link from a website. Google Extension called "Link Grabber". Works excellent. Cheers.